Why does findById return stale data with Hibernate Reactive and Panache?
I'm working with Quarkus, Hibernate Reactive, and Panache Reactive, and I noticed unexpected behavior when updating an entity in the database. I have two versions of a method that modifies a Workplace instance, but they behave differently.
Here’s the first method:
@WithTransaction
public Uni<Workplace> modifyWorkplace(Workplace request) {
    return workplaceRepository.update("nickname = ?1, version = ?2 where id = ?3", 
                                      request.getNickname(), 
                                      request.getVersion(), 
                                      request.getId())
        .onItem().transformToUni(updateCount -> {
            return workplaceRepository.findById(request.getId());
        })
        .onItem().ifNull().failWith(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Workplace not found"));
}

With this code, if I perform a load operation immediately after the update, I get the updated fields. However, with the second method, the result is different:
@WithSession
@WithTransaction
public Uni<Workplace> modifyWorkplace(Workplace request) {
    return workplaceRepository.findById(request.getId())
        .chain(existing ->
            workplaceRepository.update("nickname = ?1, version = ?2 where id = ?3", 
                                       request.getNickname(), 
                                       request.getVersion(), 
                                       request.getId())
                .chain(updateCount -> {
                    return workplaceRepository.findById(request.getId());
                })
        )
        .onItem().ifNull().failWith(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Workplace not found"));
}

In this approach, findById always returns the old, stale object instead of the updated one. To fix this, I created a third version of the method, using session.refresh, and it works correctly:
    @WithSession
    @WithTransaction
    public Uni<Workplace> modifyWorkplace(Workplace request) {
        return workplaceRepository.findById(request.getId())
                .onItem()
                .ifNotNull()
                .transformToUni(existing ->
                        workplaceRepository.update("nickname = ?1, version = ?2 where id = ?3", request.getNickname(), request.getVersion(), request.getId())
                                .onItem().transformToUni(updateCount -> {
                                    return workplaceRepository.getSession()
                                            .onItem()
                                            .ifNotNull()
                                            .transformToUni(session -> session.refresh(existing).replaceWith(existing));
                                })
                )
                .onItem().ifNull().failWith(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Workplace not found"));
    }
}

Main Questions:

Why does the second case always return stale data?
Why does using session.refresh resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Let me break down what is happening step by step:

workplaceRepository.findById(request.getId()) fetches the workplace entity and puts it into hibernates first-level cache (Session)
workplaceRepository.update(...) executes a regular SQL update statement to the database, therefore the first-level cache becomes stale
session.refresh(existing) fetches the updated workplace entity and updates the cache

In your first example, the workplace entity is not cached, because it was not fetched before.
You can learn more about hibernates first-level cache here.
